# Why for any countable set $A\subset L$, the set $cl_X(A)\subset L$

Tags: general-topology

See the example 1.18. (Sorry the picture is not clear. You can see [the link](http://picpaste.com/1-0me0yzND.png) where it is more clear. )

[image]

My question is this:

> Why for any countable set $A\subset L$, the set $cl_X(A)\subset L$ (in the last third line)?

Thanks ahead:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\supp}{\operatorname{supp}}\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$For $x\in S$ let $\supp x=\{\xi<\omega_1:x(\xi)=1\}$, the *support* of $x$. $L\subseteq S$, so $|\supp x|\le\omega$ for each $x\in L$. Suppose that $A\subseteq L$ is countable; then $\left|\bigcup_{x\in A}\supp x\right|\le\omega$. Let $I=\bigcup_{x\in A}\supp x$; it’s not hard to see that if $y\in\cl_{\Bbb D^{\omega_1}}A$, then $\supp y\subseteq I$, and therefore $y\in S$. But $D\cap S=\varnothing$, since for $x_\xi\in D$ we have $\supp x_\xi=\omega_1\setminus\{\xi\}$. Thus, $D\cap\cl_{\Bbb D^{\omega_1}}A=\varnothing$, and it follows that $D\cap\cl_XA=\varnothing$ and hence that $\cl_XA\subseteq L$.

**Added:** Let $A\subseteq X$ be countable; $D\cap\cl_XA=D\cap A$ is countable, so it suffices to find a countable network for $L\cap\cl_XA=\cl_X(L\cap A)$, and we might as well assume to begin with that $A\subseteq L$. Let $I$ be as in the previous paragraph, let $M=\Bbb D^I$, and let $\pi:S\to M$ be the projection. Then $M$ is separable and metrizable, and $\supp y\subseteq I$ for each $y\in\cl_SA$, so $\pi\upharpoonright\cl_SA$ embeds $\cl_SA$ homeomorphically in $M$, and it follows that $\cl_XA$ is separable and metrizable and therefore certainly has a countable network.

Comment: Thanks Brain. I still have a puzzeling in the example: How to see the space $X$ is $\omega$-monolithic?

Comment: @Paul: I’ve added an explanation of that part to the answer.