# A question on $\Sigma$-Product

Tags: general-topology

For a given cardinal $\kappa>\omega$, let $\Sigma=\{x\in D^\kappa: |x^{-1}(1)|\le \omega\}$ be a $\Sigma$-Product in the Cantor cube.

> Then how to show that the closure of any countable subset of $\Sigma$-Product is compact and metrizable? I could see that it is compact, however, i still cannot get that the space is metrizable.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a countable subset $C$ of $\Sigma$, since each element of $C$ has (by definition of $\Sigma$) countable support, the union $U$ of the supports of all the (countably many) elements of $C$ is still countable.  Furthermore, any element of the closure of $C$ will also have its support included in $U$.  So the closure of $C$ is homeomorphic to a subset of $D^U$, which is metrizable because $U$ is countable.

Comment: @Paul: It’s the same argument as in the added part of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/327150/12042).

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Yes, I see